# Using npm time package is it possible to test validity of timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, cron, time.h

Im using the npm time module with cron to create events correct to a timezone. The user inputs their timezone and I want to be able to check if the timezone they enter is a valid one before passing it to a cron object.

I'm using coffeescript so not exactly sure how to write it in javascript. But I would like something like the following:

```
var time = require('time');
var zone = "Europe/Lndn"; 
var x = time.checkIfValid(zone); #user misspelled London so returns false
if(x === false)
  #do something
```

This is the link to the package doesnt say anything about a validity check https://www.npmjs.com/package/time

Any ideas or workarounds for this would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Looking into the moment-timezone package which is a dependency for cron there is a method tz.zone() which returns null if a timezone is invalid or an array if it is valid.

```
var moment = require("moment-timezone");
var x = moment.tz.zone("Europe/Berlin");
if(x === null)
  #invalid timezone
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code `setTimezone` calls `tzset` which will throw an error if an invalid timezone is given. Below is the relevant code:

```
if (!rtn.tzname[1] && rtn.timezone === 0) {
    debug('got bad zoneinfo object:', rtn);
    var err = new Error("Unknown Timezone: '" + usedTz + "'");
    for (var i in rtn) {
        err[i] = rtn[i];
    }
    throw err;
}
```

You can use a [try catch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) whenever you call `setTimezone` or `tzset` to handle an invalid time zone.

Comment: I thought about maybe using that but I don't actually want to change the timezone, what I'm making is an application which will be used in many timezones and the user enters their timezone. I just want to check if it is valid before inserting it into a cron job